# Setting Up SharePoint Alerts for AD Group - No success with troubleshooting tips

Tags: active-directory, alert, distribution-lists

(This is similar to other questions on the site, however none of the solutions have worked.) I am trying to create an alert for a SharePoint list to send an email to a domain local AD group.  The associated distribution group has already been added into AD for the group.  The AD domain group has edit permissions to the list in SharePoint. I ran a full profile sync between AD and SharePoint.  When I enter the AD group in the "Send Alerts To" field, it recognizes the group, however, when I click OK I get the following error:

"The following users do not have email addresses specified:
(domain\group name)
Alerts have been created successfully but these users will not receive notifications until valid email or mobile addresses have been provided."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The AD group needs be converted to a security group and have an email address associated with it, once it does, SharePoint will send the alert to the email address and Exchange will expand it and send it to all the members of the group.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The domain group has Edit permissions to the list in SharePoint.  Is there something else I'm missing?